# Generalization of triangulation of an $n$-gon to $4$-sided regions.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinations

I was trying this following homework problem:

[image]

I was trying to find a recursion relation for $f(n)$. Note that if we delete $4$ sided region created by $3$ adjacent sides and an internal side from a $2n$-gon, then we are left with a $2(n-1)$-gon.

But I am unable to find the recursion relation, since I am not able to handle the over counting.

Need some help in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the top edge of every quadrangulation. Then every quadrangulation can be uniquely obtained by taking an ordered triple of three smaller quadrangulations, joining their marked edges to a new $4$-gon in order and setting the fourth edge of the new $4$-gon as the new marked edge (bending the resulting figure into a regular shape in the process).

[image]

In this way we get the recurrence
$$f(1)=1,f(n)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}i+j+k=n+1\\i,j,k\ge1\end{array}}f(i)f(j)f(k)$$
$f(n)$ is [OEIS A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764) and equal to $\binom{3(n-1)}{n-1}/(2n-1)$.

Comment: "every quadrangulation can be uniquely obtained by taking three smaller quadrangulations, joining their marked edges to a new 4
-gon and setting the fourth edge of the new 4
-gon as the new marked edge." This part can you explain with a figure, I am not able to understand it.

Comment: @user5210 There.

Comment: Thanks :).......